# Why did my question (about an app with no web UI) get migrated from Super User to Web Apps?

Tags: discussion, migration

LINE is an application that runs on Windows, Android, iOS. LINE has no web UI, nothing at all, in fact its website only shows static help pages. If you don't own a smartphone with a phone number you have no way to use the app, that's how it is designed.

So, when I asked [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100139/line-verify-your-identity-an-error-has-occurred-please-try-again-later) about LINE, I hesitated between Super User and Android, finally opting for the latter because my question is about the interaction between the Android app and the desktop computer app.

I was quite surprised to discover that my question got migrated to Web Apps, the most unlikely place for it.

Is it just a judgement error? Or am I missing some information?

Comment: Sometimes what the folks at [su] think should be migrated here is baffling. [I've complained about it before](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5641/1100), but it doesn't seem to have made much difference. The real place to bring this up is [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com) of course.

Comment: I'm glad to see that this got resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Five users on Super User decided that it was off topic and at least three of them decided that this site was a better place for the question. I don't know enough about the app to know for sure whether they were correct.

We as a community can decide whether or not we want to keep the question by either leaving it open or voting to close. However, if we vote to close and reject the migration the question will remain closed on Super User. You will have to go back there and argue for the question to be reopened.

I can shorten that process slightly by using my moderator vote to close, but I can't shorten the process on Super User.